# I'm trying to get information from the site, using the right css selectors, but it still returns me as if the element didn't exist

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, webdriver

> trying to build a bot to my own services, but while i'm trying to run its crashs
> login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//div[@class='loginRegisterButtons sb-login-register-buttons clearfix ember-view']//a[@class='btn signin-btn sbLoginBtn buttons1571052392296']")))
> login_button.click()

> the html

```
<div class="loginRegisterButtons sb-login-register-buttons clearfix ember-view">
    <div>
        <a class="btn signin-btn sbLoginBtn buttons1571052392296">
           <span class="btf-text">ENTRAR</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use code tags. Why are you using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` when your selector is XPATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element, so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.signin-btn.sbLoginBtn > span.btf-text"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='btf-text' and text()='ENTRAR']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```